# Analysing data within Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am new to Alfresco and I want to analyse the data present(no of files, size e.t.c., ) in an Alfresco system using C# . I am writing code following the below steps:

1. Get the login token
2. Get List of Sites inside Alfresco
3. Foreach site, get the list of Document libraries
4. Foreach document library, get all of its contents
5. Foreach file, get its info.

Is there any better approach than this?

Comment: I already few stuffs to display the data in the treeview usign dotcmis. Can you please take a look ? https://github.com/muralidharand/AlfrescoDotCMISExamples

Comment: Sample screenshot, https://github.com/muralidharand/AlfrescoDotCMISExamples/blob/0129023236de81d2bffefe7694f57668af3fac3a/github_dotcmis.png

Comment: Thanks @MuralidharanDeenathayalan , it helped!

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan Is it possible to get the last accessed date of a document in Alfresco, what property holds that info?

Comment: @Sudhakar that property is no longer filled due to performance culprits. If you want to get that information you would need to activate auditing, probably even create your custom audit application to be able to filter data correctly

Answer (score 2):

1, 2, 3 & 4 are already available in [AAAR](https://github.com/fcorti/alfresco-audit-analysis-reporting)